# how to modify plot axis labels distance from each other in R ( visually )?

Tags: r, plot, text, axis

let say I have plot below:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(c(1:4), rnorm(4), pch=16)
```

[image]

I want the distance of x axis labels' interval to be half of what R automatically has decided. by this, I mean I want to keep the values 1,1.5,2,... but vidually I want them to be closer to each other.
how can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `plot(..., xaxp  = c(x1, x2, n))` where `x1` and `x2` is the starting and ending ticks and `n` is the number of intervals between `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: I do not want to change the values or the number of labels on my x axis. what I want to keep the values 1,1.5,2,... but visually I want them to be closer to each other. ( visually )